# Uploading sas7bdat files into Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to download a sas7bdat file into python called food.sas7bdat. This is the code I'm using:

```
# Import sas7bdat package
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT

# Save file to a DataFrame: df_sas
with SAS7BDAT('food.sas7bdat') as file:
    df_sas = file.to_data_frame()

# Print head of DataFrame
print(df_sas.head())
```

I've taken the code from [datacamp](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-importing-data-in-python/importing-data-from-other-file-types-2?ex=9).
But when I run it I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sas7bdat'". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install sas7bdat?

Comment: I guess you want to "open" a sas file in Python. You don't want to upload/download a sas file to SAS. This would not make much sense. So you don't need the [SAS] tag.

Comment: @HongOoi I'm not entirley sure how to do that? Would I use pip install sas7bdat in the QT console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative:
To open a SAS dataset  in python you can simply use pd.read_sas (a function of pandas) and mainly SAS dataset has latin1 encoding. You can also check using proc contents in SAS which encoding your dataset has and use that
For E.g.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_sas("food.sas7bdat", encoding = 'latin1')
```

Comment: Thank you! WIsh I found that method first.

Comment: No worries.Glad I helped. Personally, I don't like installing external packages if I could get the job done with the already installed packages.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the above answer, would you mind accepting it @romanbilan99